# XamDataChart plotting colors and marker options

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, infragistics, marker

I am testing the newest XamDataChart from Infragistics using WPF and c#.  Does anyone have an idea as to how I can change the color of the line between data points plotted on a line chart?

I would also like to place markers on only some of the plotted points.  I can turn markers on and off for the whole series using MarkerType=”None” but have not found a way to mark just certain data points based on a data binding to a Boolean value which is also available as part of the collection used for plotting.

This seems like fairly basic stuff but so far I’m at a loss.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work, but no joy.

In the code below I have tried to simplify as much as possible without losing the essence of the problem.  It seems fairly simple and everything works except for the MarkerType data binding.  I have changed the type of the error from bool to MarkerType.  I have a large collection of AbcData objects in the AbcDataSources collection.  The data context is set on the grid.  The LineSeries gets its data ok and the chart displays the lines.

The odd thing is I have set ALL Error properties to the enum MarkerType.Circle type and in the Xaml designer the circles show up.  When the program runs they don’t.

Other Info: Im Using VS2012, .NET 4.5, Infragistics WPF 2012 V2

Once again any assistance in understanding this will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class AbcData : BindableBase
{
    private Single _dataValue;
    private MarkerType _error;

    public Single DataValue
    {
        get { return _dataValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _dataValue, value); }
    }

    public MarkerType Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _error, value); }
    }
}

public class AbcDataSource
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<AbcData> _rawMDP = new ObservableCollection<AbcData>();

    public ObservableCollection<AbcData> RawMDP
    {
        get { return _rawMDP; }
    }
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
    <Data:AbcDataSource/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="16" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ig:XamDataChart x:Name="RTChart" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalZoomable="True" WindowScaleHorizontal="0.25"
            WindowPositionHorizontal="1" HorizontalZoombarVisibility="Visible" VerticalZoomable="True"
            VerticalZoombarVisibility="Visible" PlotAreaBackground="Black" CrosshairVisibility="Visible" Background="Black">

        <ig:XamDataChart.Axes>
            <ig:NumericYAxis x:Name="YAxis" Interval="1" Label="{}{:n2}" >
                <ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
                    <ig:AxisLabelSettings Location="OutsideRight" Foreground="White" FontSize="10"
                            Extent="45" />
                </ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
            </ig:NumericYAxis>
            <ig:CategoryXAxis x:Name="XAxis" Label="{}{XDateTime:HH:mm}" ItemsSource="{Binding RawMDP}" >
                <ig:CategoryXAxis.LabelSettings>
                    <ig:AxisLabelSettings Foreground="White" FontSize="10" />
                </ig:CategoryXAxis.LabelSettings>
            </ig:CategoryXAxis>
        </ig:XamDataChart.Axes>

        <ig:XamDataChart.Series>

            <ig:LineSeries x:Name="DataValue"
                                MarkerType="{Binding RawMDP/Error}"
                                XAxis="{Binding ElementName=XAxis}"
                                YAxis="{Binding ElementName=YAxis}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RawMDP}"
                                ValueMemberPath="DataValue" />

        </ig:XamDataChart.Series>

    </ig:XamDataChart>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a marker's visibility depend on the associated data by specifying a custom marker template. If you set a DataTemplate on the MarkerTemplate property of the series then you can reference values on the underlying item via the "Item" in the data context. For example if you wanted to bind the visibility of an ellipse to a visibility property on the underlying data item, it might look something like this:

Visibility="{Binding Item.Visibility}"

If your data item had a property on it called Visibility of type Visibility.

As far as having the line change colors between points, the line series is specifically designed not to do things like this, as it could have dire consequences if you wanted a multi colored line that also had several million points, for example.

However, if you just want to do something simple, like, for example, color any section of the line that dips below a certain point red, then my suggestion would be to split that part of the data into a seperate series, with "UnknownValuePlotting" set to "DontPlot". Then, if you have any value that is above the threshold report as a null or NaN, your line will have discontinuities when the values are over that value, so only the portions of the line under the target value will show. In this way you can split a line up into the different colors you want to show.

The caution here being that if you want to have 200 thousand different line segments with different colors, you may run into a performance limitation.

Another option is to implement a custom series (Inherit from Series) that allows for each line segment to have a different color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I came to the realization earlier that MarkerType is Series based not data point based.   I will work on using a DataTemplete, which should not be difficult having the example you provided.  Do you have or know of an example for creating one’s own custom Series.  Thanks again!!!